# Put square brackets around custom item labels

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I want to put a set of square brackets *only* around custom item labels.
The default labels should remain unchanged.

See the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item [12] Second
\item Third
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item [[12]] Second
\item Third
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

In the first list, the item label `12` appears bare. I want it to appear
as `[12]`. In the second  list, if the custom label is put with an
extra of pair of brackets, the effect is almost achieved but we get a redundant space before the right bracket.

The ideal solution would be a global one, may be putting some command
or key value  along with `\begin{itemize}`, which would not require the
forced extra pair as in the second list.

(I was under the impression that [enumitem](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) would be my savior, but somehow I failed to locate the solution.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example solved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First
        \item [{[12]}] Second
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And for automatisation I would define a new command that would than apply the brackets like that. (But there may be a more elegant way to integrate it in the default `\item` command.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\citem[1]{\item[{[#1]}] }
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First
        \citem{12} Second
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result in both cases:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will want to wait for  a couple of days to see whether a solution with more automation comes up before I accept this.